# sed command in UNIX - Unable to understand

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I am new to UNIX and was going through a script file and came accross a snippet.
I tried to analyze the snippet. I read a bit about the `'sed - stream editor'` command also the `sed -e` option. 
I also executed the snippet and was ablt to get see the output. But I am unable to understand whats going on. Below is the snippet.

```
ID=101
echo ABCDEFGHIJK KLMJN | \
sed -e "1,\$s/ *$/^\"`echo $ID`\"/" \
>a.txt
```

Output is `ABCDEFGHIJK KLMJN^"101"`

There are lots of places in the script file where they have used `sed` command. Can someone help me how to decode these kind of snippets?

Comment: That is an awful command.

Comment: I'm with @123.  Please don't use this `sed` as an example of good practice, it is terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at it part by part:

```
sed -e "1,\$s/ *$/^\"`echo $ID`\"/"
       |    |    |               |
         1    2          3
```

1. You want to only work on specific lines. For that example start with the first line and end with the last. In this case it isn't needed to write that in this way. So

   ```
   sed -e "s/ *$/^\"$(echo $ID)\"/"
   ```

   does exactly the same.
2. Here comes the replace command. In this case you replace zero or more spaces between the last non-space and the line ending. If you want to find out more about this I suggest googling for `regex`.
3. The backtick (``` `` ```) is actually a 'shellism'. It causes the shell to execute the command before replacing. For a more readable way you should use `$(echo $ID)`. After that you replace the regex from 2. with the result of this, which will be `^"101"`.

And after that the result is `ABCDEFGHIJK KLMJN^"101"`

Comment: But this is not replacing spaces, if you look at the output, there are still spaces in it.

Comment: You have to know that `$` is a special regular expression character which indicates the end of the line. So the command searchs for _zero_ or more spaces after any other chars (e.g. letter) until the end of the whole string and replaces that with the mentioned string.

Comment: In this special case you could achieve exactly the same behaviour with `echo "ABCDEFGHIJK KLMJN^\"${ID}\""`.

Comment: *"you should use `$(echo $ID)`"* - or, more simply `$ID`, given that `$ID` has no spaces or shell metacharacters.